# Click in one div and change background image in other div

Tags: jquery, background

I'm trying to get by clicking on a div and another div change the backgroud-image:

```
<div class="stileone" value="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
<img scr="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"> 
</div>

<div class="stileone" value="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/">
    <img scr="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/"> 
</div>

<div id="stileone">
    Div Content
</div>
```

The JQuery:

```
$(".stileone").on("click", function() {
    $('#stileone').css('background-image', 'url(' +.val()+ ')');
});
```

But that this not working

Thanks for any help

Comment: Also note: you have `scr` instead of `src` on your images in the example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you missed fetching the URL from the clicked element's `value` attribute:

```
$(".stileone").on("click", function() {
    $('#stileone').css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).attr('value') + ')');
});
```

Also note: you have `scr` instead of `src` on your images in the example :)

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/cfvLk6dL/

Result:
[image]

Comment: The image no appear but in code source the jquery works: `<div id="alter" style="background-image: url("/uploads/images/type/myimage.png");">     
     </div>` if I put `../uploads/images/...` appears error 404 to the image

Comment: Works fine for me using Chrome. What browser are you testing with?

Comment: Screen shot added.. not sure why you don't get the images using my JSFiddle... weird (coincidence it showed Australia!) :(

Comment: Yes it works in JSFiddle, I thank you for helping, Maybe something wrong in my code

Comment: Put *your* actual code in a JSFiddle and post link so I can see what is wrong.

Comment: I did it, Thank you very much, I created a CSS class with width and height size and now worked

Answer (score 0):

val method is wrong in this context.

If you want to change background based on the value attribute of div you should use $(this).attr("value") or this.value

But if you want to change background based on clicked image source
you should try $(this).attr("src") or this.src

Also you need to change selector of the div to something like  $(this).closest("div")

```
$(".stileone").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest("div").css('background-image', 'url(' +.$(this).attr("src")+ ')');
});
```

Comment: You have several problems here (including leaving a typo in). The original does indeed target an ID-based element with `#stileone`.